# My cache folder in Android is null. Do I have to create it?

Tags: android, caching

I'm trying to cache an image obtained from a website. However, `CacheManager.getCacheFileBaseDir()` always returns `null`.

Do I need to create the cache folder in the android emulator? If yes, how I can do that? In which directory it should be created?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use that. There's a documentation issue per this answer: [How to use Android's CacheManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059831/how-to-use-androids-cachemanager/2611028#2611028). Use [`Context#getCacheDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()) for a cache dir specific to your application. You'll have to do all the cache management yourself, however, the framework will manage the contents on low disk space and when your application is uninstalled.

Comment: I had tried the codes posted on "this answer" link. however, I got a java.lang.nullPointerException

Comment: This line always return the nullPointerException. Do I need to add any permission in order to use the cache apart from the INTERNET permission?

CacheResult cache_result = CacheManager.getCacheFile(imageUrl, new HashMap());

Comment: No, what I meant by posting that is that you should not use CacheManager and the documentation for it is wrong. It is not to be for use outside of webkit. You need to use `Context#getCacheDir` if you want a simple and quick cache dir.

Comment: ok.. got it. Thanks a lot. Is there anywhere I could get the example on how I can do the quick cache?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to cache a lot of data you should use SD card for that not internal memory. So you can just create a directory on SD card and save your cache in it.

```
File cacheDir;
//Choose chache directory
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
  cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyCache");
else
  cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
//File in cache directory
File f=new File(cacheDir, "file.txt");
```

Comment: If i would like to store my cache in the sdcard, how can I do it?

Comment: Is there any example for me as a reference? because i'm quite new in android.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recommendation to make use of Context.getExternalCacheDir().

This location will be exclusively available only for your application and this API will delete this location when you uninstall the application from your android device. In order to make use of this, you must make the following statement as an entry in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```